# GCSのバケットを特定のユーザのみ公開する方法

Tags: google-cloud-storage

GCSのバケットに対してallUsers（ストレージオブジェクトの閲覧者）の権限を付与して全外部公開ではなく、特定のユーザのみWebアクセスさせたいです。可能でしょうか?

Comment: `特定のユーザ` とは、IAMに紐づくユーザを想定していますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
はい、IAMのユーザを想定しています。

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storageでは、IAMのユーザに対しバケットごとの権限（閲覧、作成、削除、管理など）を与えることが可能です。

> Identity and Access Management（IAM）は、Google Cloud Storage バケット、オブジェクトなど、Google Cloud Platform プロジェクトのリソースに対するユーザーやグループのアクセスを制御できる新しい権限ワークフローです。Cloud Storage はすでにプロジェクト レベルで IAM に対応しています。プロジェクト全体のオブジェクトやバケットに対するアクセスを許可できます。
>   バケットレベルの IAM の役割はより細かく設定できます。すべてのバケットに対するアクセスを一括で許可するのではなく、プロジェクト内の特定のバケットに対するアクセスをユーザーに許可することができます。たとえば、バケットレベルの IAM では、ストレージ管理者の役割を使用して、特定のバケットとそのすべてのオブジェクトに対する管理権限をユーザーに付与できます。このユーザーには、このバケットに対するすべての操作が許可されます。ただし、プロジェクト内の他のバケットに対しては、バケットに対する権限を付与しない限り、アクセスは許可されません。
>   [バケットレベルのアクセス制御  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/bucket-level-iam?hl=ja)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
バケット内にオブジェクトを配置して、**Webページとして**特定のIAMユーザにのみアクセスさせたいです。（開発環境なのでアクセスを絞りたい）
allUserseを追加しないと、GCS専用のURLは発行されないと思いますが、その場合は、オブジェクトをクリックして直接Webアクセスする形になりますでしょうか。